# Get IPv4 of AWS MSK kafka brokers

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, aws-nlb

I am following
[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/#:~:text=Register%20the%20MSK%20broker%20as%20a%20target%20by%20its%20IP%20address](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/#:%7E:text=Register%20the%20MSK%20broker%20as%20a%20target%20by%20its%20IP%20address).

above blog to create a private link, to access Kafka brokers. trying to imitate pattern 1 of the blog but when trying to create a target group for Network Load Balancer, the form is asking for Ipv4 for MSK, but I don't have that. AWS MSK exposes the address of the broker like this

b-3.xxxxx.xxxxx.c5.kafka.ap-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com:9094 , this is not getting accepted in the target group.

what can be the workaround?

Comment: Have you tried asking AWS MSK Support?

Comment: MSK recently make private link an out of the box feature. Do you still need to create it manually? https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/amazon-msk-multi-vpc-private-connectivity-cross-account-access/

Comment: apologies for the late reply, yeah I looked at Multi-VPC connectivity, it does not seem to be available for MSK "serverless"